# MySQL duplicate data removal with loop

Tags: mysql, loops, duplicates

I have a table called Positions which has data like this:

```
Id PositionId
1  'a'
2  'a '
3  'b '
4  'b'
```

Some of them has spaces so my idea is to remove those spaces, this is not actual table just an example of a table which has much more data. 
So i created procedure to iterate over PositionIds and compare them if trimed they match remove one of them:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE remove_double_positions()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE current VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE previous VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE positionCur CURSOR FOR SELECT PositionId FROM Positions ORDER BY PositionId;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

  OPEN positionCur;
      clean_duplicates: LOOP
      FETCH positionCur INTO current;
      IF done THEN
        LEAVE clean_duplicates;
      END IF;
        IF previous LIKE current THEN
          DELETE FROM Positions WHERE PositionId = current;
        END IF;
      SET previous = current;
  END LOOP clean_duplicates;
  CLOSE positionCur;
  END
```

For some reason it shows that 2 rows were affected but actually deletes all 4 of them and i don't know the reason why, could you help me.

Comment: Your problem is you are only seeing the results of the last delete showing 2 rows affected.  Because your cursor looks like 'a','a','b','b' and you then delete from positions where PositionId = current, what actually is happening is first fetch 'a', compare to previous, no match, no action, second fetch 'a', compare to previous = match, deletes 2 records, sql returns result 2 rows affected.  Third fetch='b', compare to previous, no match, no action, and then final fetch 'b', compare to previous = match, deletes 2 records.  SQL again reports 2 rows affected.

Comment: You need to extend your cursor to include the Id, compare current to previous and delete where Id = currentId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like under the like operator - Per the SQL standard, LIKE performs matching on a per-character basis, thus it can produce results different from the = comparison operator:...In particular, trailing spaces are significant, which is not true for CHAR or VARCHAR comparisons performed with the = operator:

```
mysql> SELECT 'a' = 'a ', 'a' LIKE 'a ';
+------------+---------------+
| 'a' = 'a ' | 'a' LIKE 'a ' |
+------------+---------------+
|          1 |             0 |
+------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

- This is true when = or like is used in where or case.

Your procedure would work as desired if you amended the delete bit to

```
 IF trim(previous) = trim(current) THEN
      DELETE FROM Positions WHERE PositionId like current;
    END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some other solution without cursor and procedure. I've check it on ORACLE. Hope it helps.

```
DELETE FROM positions
 WHERE id IN ( SELECT t1.id
                 FROM positions t1,
                      positions t2
                WHERE t1.positionId = TRIM(t2.positionId)
                  AND t1.positionId != t2.positionId
              );
```

**UPDATE**

There are some crasy things are going on with mysql. Some problem with blank at the end of a strong and this error 1093 error.

Now my solution checked with MySQL 5.5.9

```
CREATE TABLE positions (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  positionid VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO positions VALUES
( 1, 'a'),
( 2, 'a '),
( 3, 'b'),
( 4, 'b ');


DELETE FROM positions
 WHERE id IN ( SELECT t3.id FROM 
                           (SELECT t2.id
                FROM positions t1,
                     positions t2
                WHERE t1.positionid = t2.positionid
                  AND LENGTH(t1.positionid) = 1
                  AND length(t2.positionid) = 2
                   ) t3
              );

mysql> SELECT * from positions;
+----+------------+
| id | positionid |
+----+------------+
|  1 | a          |
|  3 | b          |
+----+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

This "double" from delete SQL will fix this error 1093

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't work in mysql - throws an error 1093 table 'positions' is specified twice , both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data.